# How do you decide on the most appropriate big data processing tech stack in Azure?

Tags: azure, bigdata

I'm looking for some guidance on the various "Big Data" tech stack components that azure offers, for an upcoming project we're undertaking.

In a nutshell, our platform presents advertising links in high volume. We record Counts of Impressions (how many times was a link rendered) and then richer data on each click that occurs. (click event, timestamp, url params for dimensions)

We want to start capturing richer telemetry about impressions and how our users interact with the UX components when that happens. (UX opens, scroll events, UX closed etc...)

I fully understand that there isn't ***one right answer*** here, but I'd really appreciate some guidance on what others have done in the past in similar scenarios, and any of the "gotcha's" or "considerations" you had along the way so we don't invest time in technologies that turn out to be a dead end.

Requirements
- Needs to be able to handle significant volume (10's of Millions of events per day)
- Need to be able to extract and aggregate the data and put it somewhere else where it can be reported.

Technologies we've done a first pass review on.

1. DataFactory
2. Azure Data Warehouse
3. Data Lake Storage & Analytics(U-SQL)
4. Azure Data Bricks
5. Azure Analysis Services
6. Azure Storage Explorer
7. HDInsight

In terms of what we've found so far, DataFactory looks like an obvious candidate for handling any of the ETLs from wherever we dump the acquired data -> wherever the final data resides.

SQL Data Warehouse seems like an obvious candidate for the final resting place for report data as it can be connected up to just about any reporting solution using standard SQL/ODBC connections. (we use Tableau in-house but PowerBI might be an option here)

Beyond that, the processing/analysis/transformation of data in the middle seems like something that could be done in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already mentioned that there is no one single answer I will give you an incomplete one :-)

It is regarding #3, Data Lake Storage & Analytics(U-SQL). I would not bet on the analytics part since there hasn't been any movement in this area and rumors are it is silently set aside.

About #6, Azure Storage Explorer. This is a tool, not a service. You probably mean Azure (Blob) Storage. Blob storage is a cheap and efficient store for large amounts of data but for analysis you're better of using Azure Data Lake Store or the [Gen 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction) version of it which is a blend of Data Lake Store and Blob Storage. Azure Data bricks can store its data here.

I think your are right about your observation of #1, Azure Data Factory. Azure Data Bricks is also commonly used for extraction and transformation and you can run Azure Data Bricks notebooks in the Data Factory Pipeline.

Maybe [this vid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/ignite-2018-azure-data-integration-choosing-between-ssis-azure-data-factory-and-azure-databricks/) will help you decide as well.

Comment: Thanks for this Peter. Appreciate the feedback. Will avoid DLS & Analytics so. This is really my fear, that we'll take a punt on a particular tech-stack and it'll either get EOL'd shortly after, or we'll find that it just can't do some key part of what we need.